# Matrix over division ring having one sided inverse is invertible

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

I want to see if there is any elementary way to prove the following assertion about matrices over division rings (such as not using Wedderburn's theory or tensoring techniques).

*If an $n\times n$ matrix over a division ring has left inverse, then it also has right inverse.*

The assertion has elementary proof for matrices over fields, but I am considering over division rings.

One can give some hints also.

Comment: It's a Noetherian ring, and in Noetherian ring one-sided inverses are two-sided. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63609/invertibility-of-elements-in-a-left-noetherian-ring

Comment: The duplicate is not explicitly asking about division rings but *nevertheless* all the arguments hold.  An answer to this question would necessarily cause needless duplication.